# Adding big Integers using stack in C++

Tags: c++, stack, bigdata, addition, biginteger

I am working on adding two integers using stack in C++. Here is my code:

```
bih_int.h
#include"../../../std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <stack>


stack<char> convert_to_stack(string);
string convert_to_string(stack<char>);
int toDigit(char);
char toChar(int);
int unit(int);
int carry(int);

class Big_Int
{
public:
    Big_Int();                // default constructor
    Big_Int(const Big_Int&);  // copy constructor
    Big_Int(string);          // constructor
    Big_Int(stack<char>);     // constructor
    Big_Int& operator=(const Big_Int&);
    Big_Int operator+(const Big_Int&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& , const Big_Int&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, const Big_Int&);
    void p() { cout << number << endl; }
private:
    string number;
    stack<char> abs_value;
};


big_int.cpp
#include "big_int.h"

Big_Int::Big_Int(string value)
{
    number = value;
    abs_value = convert_to_stack(number);
}

Big_Int::Big_Int(stack<char> value)

{
    abs_value = value;
    number = convert_to_string(abs_value);
}

Big_Int::Big_Int(const Big_Int& arg)
{
    number = arg.number;
    abs_value = arg.abs_value;
}

stack<char> convert_to_stack(string str)
{
    stack<char> stk;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        stk.push(str[i]);
    return stk;
}

string convert_to_string(stack<char> stk)
{
    string str;
    while (!stk.empty())
    {
        str.push_back(stk.top());
        stk.pop();
    }
    reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    return str;
}

Big_Int& Big_Int::operator=(const Big_Int& arg)
{
    number = arg.number;
    abs_value = arg.abs_value;
    return *this;
}

Big_Int Big_Int::operator+(const Big_Int& i)
{
    stack<char> num1 = convert_to_stack(number);
    stack<char> num2 = convert_to_stack(i.number);
    stack<char> res;
    int result = 0;

    while (!(num1.empty()) || !(num2.empty()))
    {
        if (!(num1.empty()))
        {
            result = +(toDigit(num1.top()));
            num1.pop();
        }
        if (!(num2.empty()))
        {
            result = +(toDigit(abs_value.top()));
            num2.pop();
        }
        res.push(toChar(unit(result)));
        result = carry(result);
    }
    if (result != 0) res.push(toChar(result));
    return Big_Int(res);
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Big_Int& num)
{
    os << num.number << endl;
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, const Big_Int& num)
{
    string s;
    is >> s;
    return is;
}

int toDigit(char c)
{
    int num = c - '0';
    return num;
}

char toChar(int num)
{

    char ch = num + '0';
    return ch;
}

int unit(int num)
{
    int n = num % 10;
    return n;
}
int carry(int num)
{
    int n = num - (num % 10);
    return n;
}

main.cpp
#include "big_int.h"

int main()
{
    string num1, num2;
cin >> num1;
Big_Int i1(num1);
cout << i1 << endl;
cin >> num2;
Big_Int i2(num2);
cout << i2<< endl;
Big_Int sum(i1 + i2);
cout << sum << endl;
}
```

It compiles and links well. But it does not add correct.
Here is what it shows when I ran it:

```
56
56

79
79

21D
```

If anybody has any ideas what`s wrong whith my program I would appreciate it.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @ NathanOliver I did exactly what is written there? but all the same I can not figure uot what is wrong whith my code.

Comment: Your copy constructor and assignment operator are unnecessary here. You should pass big objects by const reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.  First you are using the wrong container in `if (!(num2.empty()))`.

```
result = +(toDigit(abs_value.top()));
```

Should be

```
result = +(toDigit(num2.top()));
```

Secondly you are reassigning `result` in `operator+` instead of adding to it.

```
result = +(toDigit(num1.top()));
and
result = +(toDigit(num2.top()));
```

Should be

```
result += +(toDigit(num1.top()));
and
result += +(toDigit(num2.top()));
```

Lastly your `unit()` and `carry()` functions were incorrect.  With `unit()` you just want the ones place of the number so to do that you just need

```
int unit(int num)
{
    return num % 10;
}
```

Then with the `carry()` function since you want the tens place only you can use

```
int carry(int num)
{
    return num / 10;
}
```

After making those changes the code runs for all of the inputs I have tested